# pdfkit with ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-5, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

PDFKit was working fine until I turned it to an ajax. Now the javascript doesn't load graph charts before the PDF is finished. I have found some examples on how to fix it but when I try them it doesn't work.

## PDFkit code

I have found this forum that says to use `window_status` but when i do window status just hangs at Loading pages (1/6)
[============================================================] 100%

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    orientation: 'Landscape',
    javascript_delay: 5000,
    print_media_type: true
  }
end
```

`javascript_delay` works only when it is not in ajax.

`no_stop_slow_script` I don't know what that even does.

It seems to me that window.status might be my only option if only I can get it to stop from hanging.
Can anyone help?

Links that I have found that thought would have helped and explains better my request:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/wkhtmltopdf-general/vWDe5hUAyJ8/2XbXM2g1ZtYJ

Answer (score 0):

how about setting `window.status = 'ready'` inside success method in your ajax, and add `window_status: 'ready'` to your `pdfkit.rb`